# C# lambda method, set the Name property of the generated MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, lambda, system.reflection

I have a few helper methods, that spit out lambda functions based on it's parameters, basically partial application like. Now there is another place, where these Func<>'s are used, where for log and debug clarity it would be nice if I could give custom names to the generated lambda's MethodInfo, is there any way for this?

Example:

```
    public static Func<IAttrProxy, IAttrProxy, bool> NumberListEquals(double tolerance = 0)
    {
        Func<IAttrProxy,IAttrProxy,bool> lambda = (a, b) =>
        {
            if (AsNumberList(a, out IReadOnlyList<double> aValue) == false)
                return false;
            if (AsNumberList(b, out IReadOnlyList<double> bValue) == false)
                return false;
            if (aValue.Count != bValue.Count)
                return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < aValue.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(aValue[i] - bValue[i]) <= tolerance)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
        MethodInfo methodInfo = lambda.Method;
        methodInfo.Name = "NumberListEquals with tolerance: " + tolerance;
        return lambda;
    }
```

Obviously the second to last line does not compile. Is there some way to achieve the intended effect?
So that later where I use the Func<> parameter, I can get .Method.Name and it contains "NumberListEquals with tolerance:..

Comment: No. [See this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3087)

Comment: Why not create a new structure which contains the `Func<>`, and also a string name for logging?

Comment: Now that I see this is not possible, yeah, will enclose it in a struct.